# How long has Beta server been running in Astro Empires?

Tags: astro-empires

I remember playing AE some years ago.    I remember that players on beta were pretty well advanced, so I'm now curious: how long did it take for players to get 10 ds's and 100000000*10^n fts and so on?  How old is Beta server?

I was on beta server in LKW (later GE) if anyone is interested.  (I gave up after my political aspirations got the better of me.  If anyone is interested we can spin yarns of the old beta)

Comment: I was on beta for a while (on a tiny guild called the 21st). Mostly  I play Alpha though. You still on any server?

Comment: @Macha no.  I haven't played for a while.  I just got curious, cos AE is much bigger and older than I thought.  It came up in a conversation with a professor.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this website](http://astroempires.wikia.com/wiki/Beta_Server), the server was opened on November 25th, 2006.